# Putting string in a struct raises segmentation fault core dumped in C

Tags: c, string, struct

I have a problem with assigning a string to `char *` type of a structure child. I simplifies my code which raises the error:

```c
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    const char *url;
    // OR
    char *url;
} DownloadData2;

// OR

struct DownloadData{
    char *url;  
    // OR
    const char *url;
};

int main() {
    DownloadData2 *data;
    // OR
    struct DownloadData *data;

    data->url = "asmiadmimddadiadms  asdsds ad";
    // OR
    data->url = strdup("asmiadmimddadiadms  asdsds ad");
    // OR - in the struct or typedef needs to be char *url
    strcpy(data->url, "asmiadmimddadiadms  asdsds ad");

    return 0;
}
```

I search in the internet but not found what I can do!
Thank you

Comment: `data` is a pointer to a `DownloadData` which currently unitialized so pointing nowhere. Allocate memory for it.(hint: malloc). Also `url` is also just a pointer so before you would copy the string you have to allocate memory for that also.

Comment: This demonstrates a lack of basic understanding of manual memory management and strings in C.  You need to review the basics.  If you tell us why you think this code *should* work, we can certainly point out where your error in understanding lies.

Comment: @Wyck It's like you're right. I tought during create a pointer like `int *num` It allocates memory as size as `int num`. But with a different. to assign a value to a pointer first need to convert it to non-pointer. that's mean I could to it by `*num = 28(number)`. But after review I understand it's wrong. but still I don't know `char *url = "something"` is correct or not. because I think itself `"something"` is an array that allocates memory during execute.

Comment: Be aware that after proper struct allocation, `data->url = "asmiadmimddadiadms  asdsds ad";` results in the assignment of the address of the *String Literal* to `url` which is the non-mutable. (for that `const char *` is fine). However, if you need to store `url` in a way it can be modified, then you must allocate storage from `data->url` and copy the string to it. `strdup` is not part of the C-library anymore (after C99), so a manual allocation and copy may be preferable.